# NodeJS | Mongoose not updating value in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In array I'm updating a value. I am setting member `approved` value to `true` then I console.log all object and it shows the array with users updated `approved` status to `true`. But value is not saved to MongoDB after save I still see that `approved` value is `false`. This is the code:

```
    userIndex = isInMembersArray.members.findIndex(user => user.username === requestedMember);
    isInMembersArray.members[userIndex].approved = true;
    console.log(isInMembersArray) // shows data with updated user in members array
    isInMembersArray.save();
```

Comment: Use `isInMembersArray.markModified("user.approved ");` before `isInMembersArray.save()`;

Comment: That actually worked. But what that `markModified` does ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isInMembersArray.markModified("user.approved ");` before `isInMembersArray.save();`

You need to explicitly call markModified() when you update a subpath of a mixed path.

Per Docs

*Since Mixed is a schema-less type, you can change the value to anything else you like, but Mongoose loses the ability to auto detect and save those changes. To tell Mongoose that the value of a Mixed type has changed, you need to call doc.markModified(path), passing the path to the Mixed type you just changed.*